# Why doesn't memcache work in my Django?

Tags: python, django, memcached

```
from django.core.cache import cache
    def testcache():
        cache.set('test','I am putting this message in',3333)
        print cache.get('test')
```

It just prints "**None**"

This is in "ps aux":

```
dovr      2241  0.0  0.8  57824  2144 ?        Ssl  04:20   0:00 memcached -d -u root -m 3900 -p 11211
dovr      2247  0.0  3.7  83696  9800 pts/2    S+   04:20   0:00 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And this is in my settings.py:

```
CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://MYIPADRESS:11211/'
```

By the way, it worked before, but not anymore! I don't know why. So weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Django was talking to the server.
I did "nc IPADRESS 11211" .
And typed "stats"

Then, I looked that cmd_get and cmd_set were changing, so that means it's talking.

Then, I realized that I had problem with code in my views.
You can't have "space" in the key. It has to be non-spaceless (and encoded)

Answer (score 2):

You can insure that you can reach memcached from your code by logging value returned from `set()` method. Probably memcached listens on 127.0.0.1 while you are trying to connect to external interface.