# How to use memcached in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, memcached, django-1.11

I've seen all over problems using [Memcached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#memcached) in Django projects which is considered to be

> The fastest, most efficient type of cache supported natively by
> Django

For instances,

- [Why doesn't memcache work in my Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1550180/5675325)
- [How to configure Memcache for Django on Google cloud AppEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53252959/5675325)
- [Django doesn't use memcached framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41433076/5675325)
- [memcache on django is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43880976/5675325)
- [How to use memcached in django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37524184/5675325)
- [How do you confirm django is using memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29707274/5675325)
- [Configuring memcached with django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42303082/5675325)
- [What steps are needed to implement memcached in a Django application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23976476/5675325)
- [How to use memcached in django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37524184/5675325)

So, how can we then use it?

Comment: The django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache backend is deprecated as python-memcached has some problems and seems to be unmaintained. Use django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache or django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer explains how to install Memcached on Windows 10 and how to integrate it with Django through a specific client. It was validated using Memcached 1.4.4, Python 2.7 and Django 1.11.

1. In your Django project, under settings.py, add the following code in the bottom of the file

   ```
   SESSIONS_ENGINE='django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'

   CACHES = {
       'default': {
           'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
           'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
       }
   }
   ```
2. Install memcached client for Python with your virtual environment active ([python-memcached](https://pypi.org/project/python-memcached/))

   ```
   pip install python-memcached
   ```
3. Download Memcached using one of the following download links and extract it to a particular folder

- http://downloads.northscale.com/memcached-win32-1.4.4-14.zip
- http://downloads.northscale.com/memcached-win64-1.4.4-14.zip

[image: This is the memcached folder in Windows]

4. Open that folder location in the Terminal or PowerShell and run

   ```
   .\memcached.exe -h
   ```

you should get something like this

[image: memcached -help command]

5. Run the following command (-m is for the amount of memory you want to dedicate and -vvv is for extreme verbose)

   ```
   .\memcached.exe -m 512 -vvv
   ```

[image: Memcache working fine]

6. In the view you want to use cache, specify it in urls.py like

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import include, url
   from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

   from .views import IndexView

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', cache_page(60*60)(IndexView.as_view()), name="index"),
   ]
   ```
7. Go to the Django project, start the server and you should get much better results in your Time load.

[image: Improve site performance with Memcached]

Comment: Do you know if this approach is a "good" idea to implement in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment where auto-scaling may take place? I'd like to avoid paying for AWS Elasticache memcached until my app gains traction.

Comment: @Jarad might be helpful to consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33359475/5675325) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49322774/5675325)